# How to generate chaos?

Tags: dynamical-systems, chaos-theory

I would like to generate chaotic behavior that would have realistic 1/f noise properties.

For example, a time-series of price fluctuations or pendulum oscillations that would have chaotic properties.

How would I go about this task?

Comment: I meant mathematically but I would be interested to know both.

Comment: It is unclear what you mean. Is "reastic" a typo, or a term? If a term, I think it is quite obscure, so please explain it and give references. What is "f" in "1/f"? What do you mean by noise? Normally, noise implies stochasticity, which chaotic systems are not.

Comment: Pink noise is something related to chaos. And yes it’s a typo I meant realistic. Thanks!